# Codeigniter - reserving URI segment for index variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri, url-routing

Okay,

so basically what I want to do is route the url like this:

```
www.mypage.com/{controller}/[var1]/{any-function}
```

That is, segment 2 should be always reserved for passing variable into index, while any following segments should call the functions as usual. 
I've tried playing around with routes.php but couldn't quite make it work.

How should I approach this?

EDIT:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";    
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/$1/$1";    
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/$1/$1/$1";    
$route['/(:any)/news'] = "site/index/news";  
$route['12'] = 'site/index/$1/';
$route['47'] = 'site/index/$1/';
```

...

`www.mypage.com/news` - does work (calling function)

`www.mypage.com/12/` - does work (passing variable to index)

`www.mypage.com/12/news` - DOESN'T work and the goal is to make it work by doing both of the above actions in singular url. Mind you there are more functions than just 'news' so let's not limit ourselves to it.

`12`-variable; `news`-existing and working function.

Comment: > segment 2 should be always reserved for passing variable into index
How do you mean? When request is made it points specific "address" wether it is `controller_name/index` wether `controller_name/other_method`. Maybe you searching for [remapping](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)?

Comment: well I want the first/second (depending if controller is set to be in url) segment to always be a variable of an index regardless of the function I'am calling. `mypage.com/controller/news` should become `mypage.com/controller/var/news`. By default with this it will be looking for a function 'var' which doesn't exist and not using and passing that variable to index and THEN looking for a function 'news' how I want it to.

Comment: Provide your methods how those look like for now and also what you tried in routes.php file. It's hard to follow what you want from one pseudo line of code. In edited question, not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have here is that `(:any)` placeholder is greedy and no routes can jump over it to exact one mentioned. You should always keep wildcard routes at the end and use specific ones at first place.

```
$route['12'] = 'site/index/$1/';
$route['47'] = 'site/index/$1/';
$route['/(:any)/news'] = "site/index/news";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/$1/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```

Try this order. Also [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards).

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work for some reason - same as it was before. It just returns page not found error with `www.mypage.com/12/news`. I've already read before that doc you linked but it doesn't seem to cover this scenario I'am facing with variable in the constant position in the middle of url.

Comment: I didn't pay attention quite enough. Probably `site/index/news` (if I understood well that news is method too) can not be valid request. Basically you should make code that you can approach by typing right side from routes in browser. Have you solved that first? Routing is not problem if you have working code. So problem is in your controller. Post your Site controller too.

Comment: /news is working perfectly fine by itself as it routes to `site/index/news` and loads everything properly. The problem is that with current routing settings the CI just doesn't want to load any function (method) AFTER I give it index variable. Can't seem to figure out a way to tell it that after variable ('12') comes a call to function from site controller. Again, separately both actions work just fine it's just that it's either passing variable to index or calling a function, not both.

Comment: Sorry, can't help more without related code. I don't know what you mean by giving index variable to method. I am afraid your MVC approach need rewamp. I can't figure out what are you trying here and without seeing related part of code I feel helpless.

Comment: Ehm the additional code is really irrelevant here and will make it only more confusing. I will try explaining everything once more:  this `mywebsite.com/news` should change `mywebsite.com/<my_variable>/news` without braking anything. It should know exactly that first position is for variable which is being passed to controller's main index method, while the second position is for calling the method from controller(NOT a 2nd variable for index method or heaven knows what else).

Comment: As it is now `mywebsite/news` url works just fine, but it shouldn't, cause it should interpret 'news' as a variable not a function since it's in the first position and no variable is given to index method, the proper url should be `mywebsite/12/news`.

Comment: I am afraid issue can't be solved until we have site controller code in question. Great article of [how questions should be asked](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating 2 new functions in main controller (as I only needed 2 possible variables to be passed), let's call them F1; F2, and calling index *through* them accordingly

> mywebsite.com/F1 or F2/index or function

allowing me to have functions in place of vars as a workaround. So in OP example, `12` would be function (F1 or F2), not variable.